# Reescalar imagen con buena calidad android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, bitmap

Hola buenas estoy intentando re-escalar una imagen sacada con la cámara de android a unas dimensiones superiores pero se pixela.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

Luego una vez hecha la imagen la paso a base64 y la re-escalo y luego la mando

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    Bitmap resize = getResizedBitmap(bitmap,500,500);
    LinearLayout ln = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutimagen);
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(formfinal.this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    if (resize != null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        resize.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        String fotoEnBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        base64 = fotoEnBase64;
    }
    cuentaimg.add(1000+count);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (float) 0.8);
    params.setMargins(0, 2, 0, 0);
    final ImageView imgView = new ImageView(formfinal.this);
    imgView.setLayoutParams(params);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(resize);
    imgView.setId(1000+count);
    layout.addView(imgView);
    layout.addView(newImageviewimagen(formfinal.this));
    layout.setWeightSum(1);
    ln.addView(layout);
    count++;
    contadorimg++;
}
```

Funcion de reescalar

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

Me preguntaba si sabríais de alguna forma o método para que no se pixele tanto.

Comment: Claro que se pixela. Si tienes una imagen donde sabes lo que hay en 500 píxeles y quieres pasarla a una imagen con 2000 píxeles (doblarle el tamaño, vaya), debes inventarte 1500 píxeles. Escalar hacia abajo es *"fácil"*, puesto que solo tiene que eliminar píxeles que ya existen... escalar hacia arriba es difícil, puesto que te tienes que *inventar* lo que hay en medio.